# How to load wifi firmware in android?

Tags: android-wifi, android-source, android-kernel

I want to use usb wifi adapter in custom android board, so far I was able to build driver for chipset, and android is able to detect the dongle, and even creates `wlan0`. But I don't how to load firmware as there is one `bin` file. When I am trying to do `netcfg wlan0 up`, then I am getting following error `Request firmware failed with error 0xfffffffe`. 
So I need help, that to know how android includes that firmware in build.

Regards,
Yuvi

Comment: This question appears to be completely off-topic for StackOverflow as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Why there is android-source, android-kernel tag then ?

Comment: This question is too broad, not about programming and involves way too many different approaches.

Comment: Those tags are for programming-related questions about those topics. But this question has nothing to do with programming to begin with. This question belongs on Android.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I found that firmware should be copied at `/system/etc/firmware/`, reference [this link](https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/Android/WifiIntegration)

a simple copy command can be added in build script, to copy firmware before creating image.

Answer (score 0):

The path to wifi firmware in android devices is generally: 
`\system\etc\firmware\wifi`

Some devices have `system\etc\wifi` or `\system\etc\firware\wlan` as the wifi firmware path. If you connect through adb and do `ls` to one of these paths, you should be able to see firmware binary. For Qualcomm wifi, the binary has `wcnss` string in it.

As for your actual question, the firmware loading is done by the wifi driver. So if you are enable wifi through `adb shell` or through phone UI, it should load the wifi driver which should load the wifi firmware from the location mentioned above